# Sql how to combine two records in one record and select any one of the fields from tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I could not get records which i want.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by CAST(pr.District As INT) ASC) AS Row,
    pr.District, pr.Project, pr.Tenure,
    CASE pr.CompletionDate 
       WHEN NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' 
       WHEN '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' 
       ELSE pr.CompletionDate 
    END AS COMPLETIONYEAR,
    pr.AVG_PSF, pr.NoOfTransaction, 
    p.AVG_PSFRENTAL, p.RentalContract,
    ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) AS RENTAL_YIELD,
    pr.Latitude, pr.Longitude,
    CASE
       WHEN ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) < 3.0 
         THEN 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png' 
       WHEN ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) > 3.0 
            AND ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) < 4.0 
         THEN 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png'
       WHEN ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) > 4.0 
            AND ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) < 5.0 
         THEN 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png'
       ELSE 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png'
    END AS MARKER
FROM
    (SELECT
         District, Project,
         MAX(Rent) AS MAXRENT,
         ROUND(AVG((Rent / MaxArea)), +2, 0) AS AVG_PSFRENTAL,
         COUNT(PrivateURARentalID) AS RentalContract 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              PrivateURARentalID, District, Project,
              Rent, MaxArea, RentalDate
          FROM 
              PrivateURARental  
          WHERE 
              RentalDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0) 
              AND Project = 'QUEENS') [temp] 
     GROUP BY 
         Project, District 
     HAVING 
         COUNT(PrivateURARentalID) > 3) [p]
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
         District, Project, Tenure, CompletionDate,
         ROUND(AVG(psf),0,0) AS AVG_PSF,
         MAX(price) AS MAXPRICE,
         COUNT(psf) AS NoOfTransaction,
         Latitude, Longitude
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              PrivateID, District, Project, Tenure,
              CompletionDate, psf, Price,
              Latitude, Longitude
          FROM 
              Private 
          WHERE 
              [ContractDate] >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0)  
              AND Project = 'QUEENS') [temp] 
    GROUP BY 
        Project, District, Tenure, CompletionDate,
        Latitude, Longitude 
    HAVING COUNT(PrivateID) > 3) pr ON p.Project = pr.Project 
ORDER BY
    CAST(pr.District As INT) ASC
```

Now from this query I get this result:

```
                       1    3   QUEENS  99 Yrs From 16/02/1998  2002    1264    4   3.84    89  4.96    1.2925986   103.8072896 http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png
                       2    3   QUEENS  99 Yrs From 16/02/1998  2002    1231    5   3.84    89  4.85    1.2936208   103.8063609 http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png
```

for the same project i got two records.I know the reason behind this.Its due to different longitude and latitude.My question is that i want to select any of longitude from that two locations.I also want this records in a single record for this project.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If You do not want to group by field... do not group by it. :) It You want any of value for this field, You can use some aggregation function like MIN or MAX to fetch some value like this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by CAST(pr.District As INT) ASC) AS Row,
    pr.District,
    pr.Project,
    pr.Tenure,
    CASE pr.CompletionDate 
    WHEN NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' 
    WHEN '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' 
    ELSE pr.CompletionDate 
    END AS COMPLETIONYEAR,
    pr.AVG_PSF,
    pr.NoOfTransaction,
    p.AVG_PSFRENTAL,
    p.RentalContract,
    ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) AS RENTAL_YIELD,
    pr.Latitude,
    pr.Longitude,
    CASE
    WHEN ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) < 3.0 THEN 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png' 
    WHEN ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) > 3.0 and ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) < 4.0 THEN 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png'
    WHEN ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) > 4.0 and ROUND(((p.MAXRENT * 1200 )/ pr.MAXPRICE),2,0) < 5.0 THEN 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png'
    ELSE 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png'
    END AS MARKER
FROM
(
    SELECT
        District,
        Project,
        MAX(Rent) AS MAXRENT,
        ROUND(AVG((Rent / MaxArea)),+2,0) AS AVG_PSFRENTAL,
        COUNT(PrivateURARentalID) AS RentalContract 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            PrivateURARentalID,
            District,
            Project,
            Rent,
            MaxArea,
            RentalDate
        FROM 
            PrivateURARental  
        WHERE 
            RentalDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-6,0) and Project='QUEENS'
    )[temp] 
    GROUP BY 
        Project,
        District 
    HAVING 
        COUNT(PrivateURARentalID) > 3 
) [p]
inner join  (
    SELECT
        District,
        Project,
        Tenure,
        CompletionDate,
        ROUND(AVG(psf),0,0) AS AVG_PSF,
        MAX(price) AS MAXPRICE,
        COUNT(psf) AS NoOfTransaction
        ,MAX(Latitude) as Latitude,
        MAX(Longitude) as Longitude
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            PrivateID,
            District,
            Project,
            Tenure,
            CompletionDate,
            psf,
            Price
            ,Latitude,
            Longitude
        FROM 
            Private 
        WHERE 
            [ContractDate] >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-6,0) 
        and Project='QUEENS'
    )[temp] 
    GROUP BY 
        Project,
        District,
        Tenure,
        CompletionDate
        --,Latitude,
        --Longitude 
    HAVING 
        COUNT(PrivateID) > 3 
) pr ON p.Project = pr.Project 
order by CAST(pr.District As INT) ASC
```

This example hoever can fetch Latitude from one row and Longitude from other, so if You do not care about this values, I would just do not fetch them.

**EDIT**
In Your comment You stated another issue. If You are sure that data have not changed in the meantime, and without seeing it I think the `HAVING COUNT(PrivateID) > 3` clause cloud change the NoOfTransaction along with Latitude and Longitude change.
It is up to You to analyze this behaviuor and see it it is ok, or not. It is about interpreting data. Is 9 or 12 correct value?
You should be able to see what is going on by executing this query:

```
SELECT
    District,
    Project,
    Tenure,
    CompletionDate,
    psf,
    Latitude,
    Longitude
FROM Private
WHERE 
    ContractDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-6,0) 
and Project='QUEENS'
```

Comment: Its got one records but total number of transaction fields is in above example 4, 5 but now its in new records, it is 12.

Comment: Hm, maybe data in DB changed in the meantime? Can You please rerun Your orginal query and check if there is still 4 and 5? If this not solve issue, I am unable to help You without data.

Comment: See question where i mentioned data records.If we combine them then it would be consider as single record so total number of transaction would be 4+ 5 = 9